# Cordova/PhoneGap photo quality set to 1, still high quality

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm successfully taking photos (not pulling them from the media library) and uploading them to cloud storage using Cordova.

But despite setting the quality parameter to 1, images are still being stored in the 4-6mb size range, exactly the same as when it was set to 100.

I'm sure this is a quirk, wondering if anyone has had this experience and knows what might be going on. I'm using an iPhone 6 as my device. Cheers!

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(photoSuccess, captureError, {
    quality: 1,
    destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    saveToPhotoAlbum:true
});
```

Comment: Have you tried using the number 10 instead of 1? As far as I can remember the quality goes as 10-20-30-40 etc... Your value is just so low that PhoneGap probably just ignores it and doesn't compress the image.

Comment: @erol_smsr No luck, images are still between 5-6mb when I set it to 10. Thank you for responding though.

Comment: I will try some simulation on android and let you know

Comment: I made two simulations on my samsungs3. One with 50 quality and one with 10 quality. With 50, the size of my picture is about 350kb and with 10 it's about 175 kb. I have noticed that I can set up the quality in the photo capture settings of my phone. I've set to low, the size of pictures were going down to about 20kb. As I don't know much iOS, try to look in the options of capture photo of your phone , maybe you can set the capture to low .. Mine was at high

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source code for the iOS plugin, it turns out that the `quality` setting is either honored or ignored depending on what other options you supply. It boils down to this:

```
if ((options.allowsEditing == NO) && (options.targetSize.width <= 0) && (options.targetSize.height <= 0) && (options.correctOrientation == NO)){
    // Ignore the quality setting
} else {
    // Use the quality setting
}
```

The options in the `if ()` are all defaults supplied by iOS. If you specify any one of them with a non-default value, I suspect your image sizes will start changing as you'd expect. Whether or not this is a good implementation on the part of the iOS author... I guess that's a question for another day, but it seems kinda silly to me. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help Mike. Heads up to anyone who reads this. You can set the width or height in the options (but just one) this will trigger the use of the quality setting but, if you only use one, the width or height is still not specified since they were not used in conjunction. They are both needed to trigger the image resize.